# JQuery, Ajax and MVC6 parameter is null after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new in asp.net core, c# and MVC 6. I'm trying to send data over ajax to my controller.

```
function ajaxMethodData() {

$.ajax({
    url: "AjaxWithData", // hard coded for testing
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ username: "NeXT405" }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function () {
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

}

The method in the controller looks like this. The method gets invoked by the ajax request.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AjaxWithData([FromBody] string username )
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(username);

        return Json(new { success = true } );
    }
```

[image]

It looks like the data has been sent right.

If I have understood it correctly the string should now have the value from the passed data. But it is still null.

I have also tried it with void as return value (and no dataType).

```
<input type="button" value="Fatty2" onclick="ajaxMethodData()" />
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why you are adding [FromBody] for your parameter? It is your MVC method not a "WebAPI" method right?

Comment: You're not doing anything in the success method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
data: JSON.stringify({ username: "NeXT405" }),
```

To

```
data: JSON.stringify("NeXT405"),
```

WebApi only allow to get 1 parameter from body, so the variable name is not needed for basic types.

Just check: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

The last example is exactly your case